# How do I create a sorting method for an array list with generic parameters?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I'm trying to sort my array list of CDs with generic parameters. I have 4 classes: main, CD, Searching, and sorting. I have got the searching method to work but I can't figure out how to fix the sorting method. I am trying to sort by serial number.

Sorting class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Sorting<T extends Comparable<T>> {
public int selectionSort(ArrayList<T> numbers, T key) {
      int i = 0;
      int j = 0;
      int indexSmallest = 0;
      int temp = 0;  // Temporary variable for swap

      for (i = 0; i < numbers.size(); ++i) {

         // Find index of smallest remaining element
         indexSmallest = i;
         for (j = i + 1; j < numbers.size(); ++j) {

            if (numbers.get(j) < numbers.get(indexSmallest)) {
               indexSmallest = j;
            }
         }

         // Swap numbers[i] and numbers[indexSmallest]
         temp = numbers.get(i);
         numbers[i]= numbers.get(indexSmallest);
         numindex= temp;
      }
   }

   public static void insertionSort(int[] numbers) {
      int i = 0;
      int j = 0;
      int temp = 0;  // Temporary variable for swap

      for (i = 1; i < numbers.length; ++i) {
         j = i;
         // Insert numbers[i] into sorted part 
         // stopping once numbers[i] in correct position
         while (j > 0 && numbers[j] < numbers[j - 1]) {

            // Swap numbers[j] and numbers[j - 1]
            temp = numbers[j];
            numbers[j] = numbers[j - 1];
            numbers[j - 1] = temp;
            --j;
         }
      }
   }



}
```

Comment: which sorting method you mean.

Comment: In your last line of the selection sort, you have: numIndex= temp; I don't believe numIndex exists... Perhaps you mean numbers.get(indexSmallest)= temp;

Comment: I am trying to get selectionSort to work with my array list named numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `T extends Comparable<T>` you should use the `compareTo(T other)` function of the `Comparable` interface. I would do this instead:

```
public class Sorting {

    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void selectionSort(List<T> numbers) {

        int indexSmallest = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
            // Find index of smallest remaining element
            indexSmallest = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < numbers.size(); j++) {
                // use compareTo
                if (numbers.get(j).compareTo(numbers.get(indexSmallest)) < 0) {
                    indexSmallest = j;
                }
            }

            // EDIT: your swapping code was wrong
            // Swap numbers[i] and numbers[indexSmallest]
            T temp = numbers.get(i);
            numbers.set(i, numbers.get(indexSmallest));
            numbers.set(indexSmallest, temp);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your last line of the selection sort, you have:
`numIndex= temp;`
I don't believe `numIndex` exists...
Perhaps you mean
`numbers.get(indexSmallest)= temp;`?

Comment: It's understandable that you can't comment because of your low reputation, but, that is clearly not a reason to use an answer as comment, like everybody else, you'll need to wait until you get enough reputation to do it, you may delete this post, Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry azro, I did mean to add an answer. And I believe that that's the answer to the problem. From what I can see, it's the only error in their code (unless I'm missing something)